# Meteor checkbox for selecting record and display total

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, input

I am new to meteor and my background is JDEdwards consultant with 15 years of experience. Recently interested in web application and building small application with meteor. Here is my issue.

I have five rows of data in HTML table with checkbox and it has amount field. I have one input text just before table (Invoice Total:). I would like to select checkbox from table and it will display total value in Invoice Total. I have class in both places. For example, If I select three records with amount 55,10 and 5, Invoice total should be 70. How do I achieve this using meteor client JS. Can I get some help on this?

HTML

```
   <template name="dashboard">
     <div class="col-sm-9">
     <div class="well">
     <h4>Dashboard</h4>
    <label class="totalamt">Invoice Total:
     <input type="text" value={{invtotal}}>
     </label>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th></th>
    <th>Company Id</th>
    <th>Invoice Id</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Currency</th>
     <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     {{#each invoiceList}}
     {{>invoiceRow}}
     {{/each}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template name="invoiceRow">
    <tr class="success">
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="{{calcamt}}" class="toggle-checked"/></td>
<td>{{division_id}}</td>
<td>{{invoice_id}}</td>
<td>{{amount}}</td>
<td>{{currency}}</td>
<td>{{description}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
```

**

- **client JS**

**

```
 Router.route('/dashboard',function(){
     this.render('dashboard');
   Template.dashboard.invoiceList = function(){
     return Invoice.find();
     }
   Template.invoiceRow.events({
    'click.toggle-checked':function(evt,tmpl){

        }
   });
   Template.invoiceRow.select_invoice = function(){
     return Session.get('select_invoice')
   }
  })
```

Thanks,
Kaushik Roy

Comment: Can you share your code so far? (relevant snippet to show exactly what you're trying to do)

Comment: Here is my code and Thanks for your reply.

Comment: what is the issue ? from the clientjs, that is not the correct way to define  `router` with `iron:router`, `event`, `helper` of `meteor`

Comment: I have five rows of data in HTML table with checkbox and it has amount field. I have one input text just before table (Invoice Total:). I would like to select checkbox from table and it will display total value in Invoice Total. I have class in both places. For example, If I select three records with amount 55,10 and 5, Invoice total should be 70. How do I achieve this using meteor client JS. Can I get some help on this?